# React hooks exhaustive-deps infinite loop with async function which uses state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I'm trying to handle an async function to insert data in a database. Unfortunately the eslint `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` requires me to add my `score` state in the `useCallback`. Although when I add this my app get in an infinite loop state.

When I add `eslint-disable-line` on the callback requirements line my code runs perfectly fine. Why is this rule in there, and how to solve it the correct way without disabling the eslint rule?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import { insertData } from 'ducks/data';

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const sliderData = useSelector((state) => state.data.sliders);
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

  const handleData = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(insertData(score));
  }, [dispatch]); // eslint-disable-line

  useEffect(() => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(sliderData)) {
      const sliders = Object.values(value);
      const totalSliderScore = sliders.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

      setScore((prevScore) => prevScore += totalSliderScore);

      // Last slider in array
      if (key === 'lastKey') {
        handleData();
      }
    }
  }, [sliderData, handleData]);

  return ...
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a reference of the latest score so that it will not cause the loop

```
    const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
    const latestScore = useRef();

    const handleData = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(insertData(latestScore));
    }, [dispatch,latestScore]); // eslint-disable-line

    useEffect(() => {
        ...
        latestScore.current = score
        }
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

any state variable used in a `useCallback` should be included in the dependency list otherwise you might get stale data of that variable.

```
const handleData = useCallback(() => {
dispatch(insertData(score));
}, [dispatch, score]);
```

and why do you need the function `handleData` in the dependency list of `useEffect` ? Isn't that causing the loop. I think also changing to the following should solve the infinite loop.

```
useEffect(() => {
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(sliderData)) {
  const sliders = Object.values(value);
  const totalSliderScore = sliders.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

  setScore((prevScore) => prevScore += totalSliderScore);

  // Last slider in array
  if (key === 'lastKey') {
    handleData();
  }
}
}, [sliderData]);
```

Comment: Because the useEffect requires handleData as an dependency since it's used in the useEffect. Basically this is the same eslint rule as in the useCallback

Comment: but `handleData` is a function which will not change, we only need those values in the dependency list for which after any change we need to allow to the `useEffect callback` to run again.